# Android exported apk with proguard runtime error "Unknown Source"

Tags: android, apk, proguard, signed

I got Some `Unknown Source` error when running exported apk with `proguard`.

This is my **Proguard config file**

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature, *Annotation*



-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}


-keep class com.android.myapp.AddContacts { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.DBController { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.Enc_dec { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.GPSMgmService { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.HTTPSendLog { protected *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.HTTPSendLogObject { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.HTTPServiceHandler { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.MainHandler { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.ReceiveSMS { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendCallLogs { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendCallLogsThread { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendContactsLogsThread { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendLocationLogsThread { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendLogsService { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendRecordedAudioLogsThread { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SendSMSLogsThread { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SentRecieveCalls { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.SentSMS { *; }
-keep class com.android.myapp.StartServiceReceiver { *; }


# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-libraryjars httpclient-4.3.6.jar
-libraryjars httpcore-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars httpmime-4.3.6.jar
-libraryjars commons-codec-1.9.jar
-libraryjars commons-io-2.4.jar
-libraryjars android-support-v4.jar



# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Here is Errors

```
    11-10 18:04:53.426: E/AndroidRuntime(26360):    at com.android.myapp.HTTPServiceHandler.makeServiceCall(Unknown Source)
11-10 18:04:53.426: E/AndroidRuntime(26360):    at com.android.myapp.HTTPSendLog.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
11-10 18:04:53.426: E/AndroidRuntime(26360):    at com.android.myapp.HTTPSendLog.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
11-10 18:05:00.801: I/ActivityManager(363): Process com.android.myapp (pid 26360) has died.
```

I read many question/answer threads on internet but my problem hasn't solved yet.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is no error. If you want to retain information about source line numbering you have to add the following to your ProGuard configuration ([source](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#stacktrace)):

```
-renamesourcefileattribute ProGuard
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```